# Dynamic suffix in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to create a suffix which can differentiate between number. Here is an example : If i type 1 then suffix should be "- day" and for anything greater than 1 suffix should be "-days". At the same time i am using datedif formula in the active cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a custom number format.

```
[>1]0\-\d\a\y\s;[=1]0\-\d\a\y;0\-\d\a\y\s;[red]@
'optional to make day and days line up
[>1]0\-\d\a\y\s;[=1]0\-\d\a\y_);0\-\d\a\y\s;[red]@
'line up day with days, don't display zeros
[>1]0-\d\a\y\s;[=1]0-\d\a\y_);;[Red]@
```

[image]

Comment: nice, I haven't got the chance to use Format Cells, with days and `[Red]`

Comment: 2 things:  Put the `[=1]` at the start, and you can delete the `[>1]` clause, and why Escape the characters with `\ ` - if you're using more than 2 it's easier to use strings: `[=1]#0"-day"_);#0"-days";[Red]@`

Comment: 1. agreed but this demonstrates the functionality better imo. 2. I use this method in vba and hate doubling up quotes in  a quoted string.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answers, apart from this i need is when the value is zero , the cell should remain blank .

Comment: tbh, I'm more than a little dismayed to hear that you couldn't figure that modification out for yourself.